# NS2, Otcl: using a variable of an owned instance within a class

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2, otcl

I'm using NS2 to create some new classes in C++ and then link them to otcl. The linkage and everything works, but when I try to use the otcl variables in an object, I'm having a trouble.

For example, suppose I have a class "`Node`" with the variable `X`. In the code I want to set this value and later on use it in some if-statements.

Setting the variable is no problem using this code:

```
$node1 set x 4
```

Now the problem I'm having is when I try to use this variable x anywhere. In C++ we could use a general variable (i.e., `y`) and say "`y=node.x`" and then use `y` in some if-statements. I have tried to look for a method to perform the same thing in otcl, but failed.

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Donal for the answer. But I found what I really needed (and it worked), which is something like this:

```
set x [$class set y]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `OTclSetInstVar` and `OTclGetInstVar` to write and read instance variables respectively. They're defined in `otcl.h`, which is a plain C header file, and their use should be pretty obvious if you're used to general Tcl APIs.

If you've got a version of NS2 built on top of the newer XOTcl (which I gather exists from the projects that the XOTcl main author is involved with through Google Summer of Code over the past couple of years) then the APIs are `XOTclOSetInstVar` and `OTclGetInstVar` in (or rather included off of) `xotcl.h`. The type signatures are *not* the same though; they're only logically drop-in replacements, and not actual drop-ins. (OTcl uses pure string-based APIs, XOTcl uses much more efficient – but complex – `Tcl_Obj`-based APIs.)